# Checking double values using <c:if> JSTL statement

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a code like this,

```
<c:if test="${total gt "+"<%=assignedValue%>"+"}">
<p>Your total value is greater than the assignedValue</p>
</c:if>
```

and that "addignedValue" is return from java as,

```
<%
      Calculate cal = new Calulate();
      double assignedValue = Double.parseDouble(cal.getAssignedValue());%>
```

But i can't able to check that inside the  tag...

Any Help will be appreciated. Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

You must create a scoped variable from your scripting variable.
Instead of using

```
<%
  Calculate cal = new Calulate();
  double assignedValue = Double.parseDouble(cal.getAssignedValue());%>
```

use

```
<%
   Calculate cal = new Calulate();
   pageContext.setAttribute("assignedValue", cal.getAssignedValue());
%>
```

and

```
<c:if test="${total gt assignedValue}">
    <p>Your total value is greater than the assignedValue</p>
</c:if>
```